# Get documents with sub.k='a' if sub.v is the highest of all sub.v in this document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure and want to get all documents which have `'mymap.k'='test_1'` BUT only if the corresponding `mymap.v` is the highest of the document.

```
{ "name":"testDoc1", "mymap": [{"k":"test_1","v":5},{"k":"test_2","v":3}] }
{ "name":"testDoc2", "mymap": [{"k":"test_1","v":2},{"k":"test_2","v":4}] }
{ "name":"testDoc3", "mymap": [{"k":"test_3","v":6},{"k":"test_2","v":4},{"k":"test_3","v":6}] }
{ "name":"testDoc4", "mymap": [{"k":"test_3","v":2},{"k":"test_1","v":7},{"k":"test_2","v":4}] }
```

So the result should be:

```
{ "name":"testDoc1" }
{ "name":"testDoc4" }
```

Can I achieve this with the aggregation framework?

My approach is to do something like the following. But this isn't working at all.

```
db.col.aggregate([
 {$match:{"mymap.k":"test_1"}},
 {$unwind:"$mymap"},
 {$group: {_id:"$_id", mymap: { k:{$first:"$mymap.k"}, v:{$max:"$mymap.v"}}}}
])
```

Comment: According to your matching requirement `'mymap.k'='test_1'`,  `{ "name":"testDoc2" }` should also be in the aggregation results by the way.

Comment: No, I don't want to output `testDoc2` because the value of `v` to `mymap.k=test_1` is not the highest of the document. `v`of `mymap.k=test_2` is higher.
I edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: I think you could do this with the aggregation framework, but generally using aggregation to do more general queries (try to return documents that look like ones from the original collection) is iffy. Can you explain what the motivation is behind this search requirement? What will you do with the results? What do they mean? It might give us a better approach, or, failing that, demonstrate why aggregation is the best approach.

Comment: @wdberkeley First, thanks for your comment and sorry for the very late answer. I want to use the aggregation framework because I build a complex query with a lot of filters and stuff. The problem above is a part of the whole query only. But all of this should not be considered in your answers: if there is a different way to solve the problem above, I may find a solution for the rest. At the moment I use a filter on the application side to solve the problem. So I would be happy if anyone knows a solution, no matter if per aggregation, map&reduce or query.